# How to extend existing cdt builder to make custom builder plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to create a custom eclipse builder plugin to build a my customized C project. I want to run a list of python script before the build starts. I am able to run my python script using my custom builder, but I don't how to call an existing builder(such as cdt and jdt)from my plugin. i.e My builder must run the python script first, right after completing the the script execution it should start regular C build. I want these two should be in single builder plugin, not as two separate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does [`ExternalBuildRunner#invokeBuild`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/src/org/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/core/ExternalBuildRunner.java#n69) not work?

Comment: Oh. This looks really interesting.  Thank you so much.    'code'  new ExternalBuildRunner().invokeBuild(kind, project, configuration, builder, console, markerGenerator, projectBuilder, monitor); 'code' I tried like this. But parameters like " configuration, builder, console, markerGenerator, projectBuilder" are not available. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IProject`

```java
public void build(int kind, String builderName, Map<String, String> args, IProgressMonitor monitor)
```

method to call a specific builder. `args` and `monitor` can be `null`.

`kind` is the build kind, something like `IncrementalProjectBuilder.FULL_BUILD` for a full build.

`builderName` is the id of the builder as defined in the `>org.eclipse.core.resources.builders` extension point.

Comment: I did not understand!! "org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.genmakebuilder" is the builder I need to invoke. How can I call this from my custom plug-in. Do you have a sample?

Comment: So you use `"org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.genmakebuilder"` as the `builderName` in this call. No I don't have an example. Added a bit more info to the answer.

Comment: `public class MyBuilder extends IncrementalProjectBuilder {

 public static final String BUILDER_ID = "com.gs.custombuilder.myBuilder";

 @Override
 protected IProject[] build(final int kind, final Map<String, String> args, final IProgressMonitor monitor)
   throws CoreException {
  // get the project to build
  IProject project = getProject(); 
  applyPythonScript(project.getLocation().toOSString());
  
  project.build(kind, "org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.genmakebuilder", args, monitor);
  System.out.println("Custom builder triggered: "+project.getName());  `

Comment: I have added my code above. This is unfortunately not working. It looks like it is not invoking that particular line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without writing any code if you want.

1. Open project properties.
2. Choose *Builders* and press *New*:

[image]

3. Choose *Program* and press *OK*:

[image]

4. Fill in everything to launch your Python:

[image]

5. Make sure you "refresh" whatever you are generating:

[image]

6. Press OK then move your new builder to the top, then Apply and Close:

[image]

7. Build your project

You can add an additional builder in the same way to do the Clean by adding it to run during the "Clean" phase by editing settings in the *Build Options*:

[image]

In the Builders list this looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. However, my requirement is different. I need some stuff that can invoke an existing builder from custom builder.